# SSL errors when using Npgsql and SSL certificate authentication

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql, ssl-certificate, npgsql

I'm having trouble establishing a connection to a PostgreSQL database that is configured only to accept a valid SSL certificate. I can connect using pgAdmin III with the appropriate certificate and key, but I cannot get it working with Npgsql. When I try to open a connection to the database, I get `System.IO.IOException: The authentication or decryption has failed`. Here is my code:

```
NpgsqlConnectionStringBuilder csb = new NpgsqlConnectionStringBuilder();
csb.Database = "database";
csb.Host = "psql-server";
csb.UserName = "dreamlax"; // must match Common Name of client certificate
csb.SSL = true;
csb.SslMode = SslMode.Require;

NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection(csb.ConnectionString);
conn.ProvideClientCertificatesCallback += new ProvideClientCertificatesCallback(Database_ProvideClientCertificatesCallback);
conn.CertificateSelectionCallback += new CertificateSelectionCallback(Database_CertificateSelectionCallback);
conn.CertificateValidationCallback += new CertificateValidationCallback(Database_CertificateValidationCallback);
conn.PrivateKeySelectionCallback += new PrivateKeySelectionCallback(Database_PrivateKeySelectionCallback);

conn.Open(); //System.IO.IOException: The authentication or decryption has failed
```

The callbacks are defined like this:

```
static void Database_ProvideClientCertificates(X509CertificateCollection clienteCertis)
{
    X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2("mycert.pfx", "passphrase");
    clienteCertis.Add(cert);
}

static X509Certificate Database_CertificateSelectionCallback(X509CertificateCollection clientCerts, X509Certificate serverCert, string host, X509CertificateCollection serverRequestedCerts)
{
    return clienteCertis[0];
}

static AsymmetricAlgorithm Database_PrivateKeySelectionCallback(X509Certificate cert, string host)
{
    X509Cerficate2 thisCert = cert as X509Certificate2;
    if (cert != null)
        return cert.PrivateKey;
    else
        return null;
}

static bool MyCertificateValidationCallback(X509Certificate certificate, int[] certificateErrors)
{
    // forego server validation for now
    return true;
}
```

I set breakpoints confirming that each callback was returning something valid, but still the IOException is thrown.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fixed this problem by modifying the Npgsql source. Rather than using Mono's `Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslClientStream`, I changed it to use `System.Net.Security.SslStream` instead. These were the steps I took:

1. Modify `NpgsqlClosedState.cs`:

   1. Remove the `using Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls;` directive and the one below it.
   2. Add a `using System.Net.Security;` directive.
   3. In the `NpgsqlClosedState.Open()` method, where it says `if (response == 'S')`, changed it to:

      ```
      if (response == 'S')
      {
          //create empty collection
          X509CertificateCollection clientCertificates = new X509CertificateCollection();

          //trigger the callback to fetch some certificates
          context.DefaultProvideClientCertificatesCallback(clientCertificates);

          // Create SslStream, wrapping around NpgsqlStream
          SslStream sstream = new SslStream(stream, true, delegate(object sender, X509Certificate cert, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors errors)
          {
              // Create callback to validate server cert here
              return true;
          });
          sstream.AuthenticateAsClient(context.Host, clientCertificates, System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Default, false);
          stream = sstream;
      }
      ```
2. Modify `NpgsqlConnection.cs`, remove the `using Mono...` directives. This will cause a number of errors regarding missing types, in particular, these will be regarding 3 sets of delegate/event combos that use Mono types. The errors will always appear in groups of three because these callbacks all tie in with Mono's `SslClientStream` class. Remove each group of three and replace it with a single `ValidateServerCertificate` delegate/event. This single event should be used in the constructor for the `SslStream` class that was used in step 1.3 above.
3. The changes to `NpgsqlConnection.cs` will trigger more errors in other files `NpgsqlConnector.cs`, `NpgsqlConnectorPool.cs` etc. but the fix is the same, replace the 3 Mono-based callbacks with the new `ValidateServerCertificate`.

Once all that is done, Npgsql can be used without Mono components and with (for me) working SSL certificate authentication.

My pull request on github can be found [here](https://github.com/franciscojunior/Npgsql2/pull/25).

Comment: Thank you very much for your feedback! Would you mind to create a pull request with your patch? http://git.npgsql.org This would be very helpful for others who are receiving errors when using Npgsql and SSL. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @FranciscoJunior: Hi, I created a pull request. I am new to git, so not sure if I did it properly.